# why is std::lock_guard not movable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, standards, movable

Why is `std::lock_guard` not movable, it would make code so much nicer:

```
auto locked = lock_guard(mutex);
```

instead of

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locked(mutex);
```

Is there something wrong with creating your own version, like:

```
template <typename T> class lock_guard_
{
  T* Mutex_;
  lock_guard_(const lock_guard_&) = delete;
  lock_guard_& operator=(const lock_guard_&) = delete;
public:
  lock_guard_(T& mutex) : Mutex_(&mutex)
  {
    Mutex_->lock();
  }
  ~lock_guard_()
  {
    if(Mutex_!=nullptr)
      Mutex_->unlock();
  }
  lock_guard_(lock_guard_&& guard)
  {
    Mutex_ = guard.Mutex_;
    guard.Mutex_ = nullptr;
  }
};

template <typename T> lock_guard_<T> lock_guard(T& mutex)
{
  return lock_guard_<T>(mutex);
}
```

?

Any fundamental reason it would be a bad idea to make it movable?

Comment: Well, you do have `unique_lock`. It might just be to make the interface as simple as possible.

Comment: thanks, I have overlooked unique_lock :-) So I guess this answers my question: No there is no reason. Imo making it movable doesn't really make the interface more complicated but more usable and compatible with modern c++.

Comment: @valoh: If it was movable it would need to have a state where it doesn't hold a the lock. That makes it redundant, since it would offer exactly the same functionality as `unique_lock` (though I would argue that it is mostly redundant anyway). Therefore if  `lock_guard` is desired as a seperate class it can't really be movable.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`lock_guard` is *always* engaged; it always holds a reference to a mutex and always unlocks it in its destructor.  If it was movable then it would need to hold a pointer instead of a reference, and test the pointer in its destructor.  This might seem a trivial cost, but it is C++ philosophy that you don't pay for what you don't use.

If you want a movable (and releaseable) lock you can use `unique_lock`.

You might be interested in [n3602 Template parameter deduction for constructors](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3602.html), which removes the need for `make_` functions.  It won't be in C++14 but we can hope for C++17.

Comment: N3602 is [EWG issue 60](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3836.html#60). EWG is definitely in favor of the paper, but there are some issues that need ironing out.

Answer (score 14):

You can do:

```
auto&& g = std::lock_guard<std::mutex> { mutex };
```

Obviously this isn’t entirely satisfactory as this performs no deduction. Your attempt at a deducing factory is almost there save for the fact that you need to use list-initialization to return a non-movable object:

```
template<typename Mutex>
std::lock_guard<Mutex> lock_guard(Mutex& mutex)
{
    mutex.lock();
    return { mutex, std::adopt_lock };
}
```

which allows for [`auto&& g = lock_guard(mutex);`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c7ef1fe9cdc33e8).

(The awkward dance with `std::adopt_lock` is due to the unary constructor being explicit. So we can’t do `return { mutex };` as that’s a disallowed conversion, while `return std::lock_guard<Mutex> { mutex };` performs list-initialization of a temporary — which we can’t then move into the return value.)

Comment: This is nifty, slightly scary, and I might just steal it. :p

Comment: That's cool, but why the extra level of aggregation?  It seems to work without it: https://ideone.com/KDs8qI

Comment: @VaughnCato This may have been a misconception of mine, as the language that I thought applied only to aggregates seems to work for non-aggregates just as well. Admittedly those aren’t my favourite areas of the Standard, so I welcome any light shed on them. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: I looked it up.  According to 6.6.3p2, "A return statement with a braced-init-list initializes the object or reference to be returned from the function by copy-list-initialization (8.5.4) from the specified initializer-list.".  Even though it is copy-list-initialization, that doesn't mean there is a copy made.  The only thing I can see that makes copy-list-initialization special is that it doesn't allow the use of explicit constructors.  Otherwise, it is regular list-initialization, and no copy is involved.